# Calling a function in parent component from a child component - React+flux+alt

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I am using flux+alt+es6 structure in my react application.I want to update parent state with my child component details.

Parent function:

```
handleChange(name, e) {
    const change = {};
    change[name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(change);
    console.log('---state:--', this.state);
  }
```

Child Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Input, Button, Glyphicon } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class TextBoxesSet extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  _onRemoveName = (id) => {
    this.props.name.slice(id, 1);
  }
  static getPropsFromStores() {
    return {name: 'en', description: '', AttributeSectionName: []};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <div className="">
          <Input type="select" placeholder="select" wrapperClassName="col-xs-4"
          value={this.props.name} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'name')} >
            <option value="one">One</option>
            <option value="two">Two</ption>
            <option value="three">Three</option>
          </Input>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-1">
          <Button bsSize="small"><Glyphicon glyph="remove" onClick={this._onRemoveName} /></Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  handleChange(name, e) {
    ParentComponent.handleChange(name, e);
  }
}
TextBoxesSet.propTypes = {
  name: React.PropTypes.object,
  description: React.PropTypes.object,
  AttributeSectionName: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.object)
};
```

How can I access function in parent component from a child component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass it as a prop, f.ex:

```
<TextBoxesSet handleChange={this.handleChange} />
```

And then:

```
this.props.handleChange(name, e);
```

You need to add it as a propType as well:

```
handleChange: React.PropTypes.func
```

You might need to bind the correct context as well in the parent constructor if you need access to `this` in the function:

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
```

Comment: thanks but this.setState(change) is failing when I calling function from child component

Comment: `Error: Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function`

Comment: @AnushaNilapu Right, React disabled autobinding in the class model. So you need to bind the right context, in the constructor or elsewhere: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding